# i make hover tag be smart?

Tags: jquery, function, hover

i have problem about .hover(), i know i can add two function for it but 
look at these codes:

```
<style>
.a{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:red;
}
.b{
position:absolute;
top:100;
left:0;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:blue;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function){
     $('.a').hover(function(){                //both objects are div
         $('.b').animate({left:"100px"},500);
     },
     function(){$('.b').animate({left:"-100px"},500);
     });
});</script>
```

its simple and work but problem is here:
i want when mouse enter .a area and .b go to next position then mouse position check, if mouse move out of .a and thats path be to .b object second function of hover() dont run and let .b stay new position until mouse move out from both then next command run.
waiting for best answer! :)
thanks

Comment: Provide your HTML also or make a fiddle demo

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. Could you rephrase it in coherent sentences and use some interpunction please?